# Should $\to$-elimination always have precedence over $\lnot$-elimination when transforming formulas to Prenex CNF?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, automated-theorem-proving

I'm currently learning the resolution method of proof and before it can be applied we need to transform a FOL formula into prenex, then skolemise it, then transform it to CNF, correct? I encountered a doubt when converting the following formula to CFN:

1) $\forall x \forall y ((H(x,y) \land C(y)) \to \lnot\exists z(H(x,z)\land Mouse(z)))$

Now, if I use $\to$-elimination before $\lnot$-elimination, I'll get the following transformation:

2) $\forall x \forall y (\lnot(H(x,y) \land C(y)) \lor \lnot\lnot\exists z(H(x,z)\land Mouse(z)))$

forcing me to convert $\lnot \lnot \exists z$ to $\exists z$

and get the following formula after $\lnot$-elimination:

3) $\forall x \forall y ((\lnot H(x,y) \lor \lnot C(y)) \lor \exists z(\lnot H(x,z)\lor \lnot Mouse(z)))$

And, after moving quantifiers to the front:

4) $\forall x \forall y \exists z ((\lnot H(x,y) \lor \lnot C(y)) \lor \lnot H(x,z)\lor \lnot Mouse(z)))$

Which will inevitably force me to skolemize the existential quantifier and finally arrive at:

5) $\forall x \forall y ((\lnot H(x,y) \lor \lnot C(y)) \lor \lnot H(x,f(x,y)))\lor \lnot Mouse(f(x,y))))$

Now, this is where my doubt comes into play. Had I used $\lnot$-elimination before $\to$-elimination -between 1) and 2)-, I'd have arrived at:

2*) $\forall x \forall y (\lnot(H(x,y) \land C(y)) \lor \forall z \lnot(H(x,z)\land Mouse(z)))$

By doing so, I wouldn't have to skolemize the existential quantifier away and would not have a skolem-function in my result. My question is: can I save myself the hassle of skolemising the existential quantifier in this way or will I run into trouble later on?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why the second $\lnot$ in $¬¬∃z$ ? Check again step 2.

Comment: Step 2) must be : $∀x∀y(¬(H(x,y)∧C(y))∨¬∃z(H(x,z)∧Mouse(z)))$.

Comment: Oh, now I feel dumb. Indeed there's no reason for that second negative. I guess that was such an obvious mistake that I overlooked it by assuming it was correct. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) $\forall x \forall y ((H(x,y) \land C(y)) \to \lnot\exists z(H(x,z)\land Mouse(z)))$
>
> Now, if I use $\to$-elimination before $\lnot$-elimination, I'll get the following transformation:
>
> 2) $\forall x \forall y (\lnot(H(x,y) \land C(y)) \lor \lnot\lnot\exists z(H(x,z)\land Mouse(z)))$

No, you don't. You get:

$\forall x \forall y (\lnot(H(x,y) \land C(y)) \lor \lnot\exists z(H(x,z)\land Mouse(z)))$

and thus:

$\forall x \forall y (\lnot(H(x,y) \land C(y)) \lor \forall z \neg (H(x,z)\land Mouse(z)))$

and thus you don't get an existential to skolemise that way either.

In general, when you put a statement in prenex, the nature of the quantifiers will be forced. That is, you will not be able to get a different quantifier depending on the order in which you perform the steps. So, the fact that you got $\forall x \forall y \exists z ...$ one way,  but $\forall x \forall y \forall z ...$ thew other way, immediately means that something went wrong.

However, what *can* happen, is that the *order* of the quantifiers can change. That is, doing steps in one order, you may get $\forall x \exists y...$, and doing it a different way, you might get $\exists y \forall x...$, and in that case doing it the second way avoids you having to introduce a function when skolemising.